# Returning value from TableAdapter.Update() method that uses stored procedures

Tags: c#, data-binding, ado.net

I have a `DataSet` containing a series of similar `DataTable` objects. All tables use `TableAdapters` to handle insert, update, and delete interactions with the database. As each table represents a database view, I am using stored procedures from the database for the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, and `DeleteCommand` properties (as opposed to automatically generated DB direct methods).

Each of the aforementioned stored procedures returns a value that I would like to capture when calling the `TableAdapter.Update()` method. Unfortunately, it seems the method only returns the number of rows affected by the queries it executes.

I am aware that if I configure these procedures to be independent queries in the adapter, I can set their `ExecuteMode` to `Scalar` and retrive the return values that way. I would like to leave the procedures as the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, and `DeleteCommand` properties of the `TableAdapter`, as this allows for much simpler code on the front end, where these `DataTables` are bound to a `DataGridView` object. Is there a way in which I could obtain the return value from the respective stored procedure on the `TableAdapter.Update()` call?

Comment: Since the intent of return values is to communicate error conditions, not data, you might consider using `OUTPUT` parameters that can then be accessed on the command after execution.

Comment: @Crowcoder, that would be better. I believe I am going to run into the same issue though. The update command passes all parameters to the appropriate stored proc (insert, update, or delete) through columns mapped from the `DataTable`. As far as I know, I do not think I could access the output parameter without, again, the stored procs being independent in the `TableAdapter`, as opposed to being mapped to its `InsertCommand`, etc. properties.

Comment: I don't think I've done this before but you should be able to [access the CommandCollection](https://forums.asp.net/t/1795021.aspx?How+to+get+the+SelectCommand+value+of+a+TableAdapter+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to access the values I needed by essentially extending the appropriate designer generated `TableAdapter` classes.

I ended up adding a property to the appropriate `TableAdapter` class that retrieved the value of the appropriate output parameter for each command (`InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand`, and `DeleteCommand`). As I am calling Update() on each discrete edit made to the `DataTables` in question, only one of the values should ever be not null. The value that is not null is returned by the property getter. See code below.

```
public partial class ExcelViewTableAdapter
{
    public int? UpdateReturnValue
    {
        get
        {
            int? insertVal = (int?)this._adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters["@NextNoteInfoID"].Value;
            int? updateVal = (int?)this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters["@NextNoteInfoID"].Value;
            int? deleteVal = (int?)this._adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters["@DeletedNoteIdentifier"].Value;

            if (insertVal != null && updateVal == null && deleteVal == null)
            {
                return insertVal;
            }
            else if (updateVal != null && insertVal == null && deleteVal == null)
            {
                return updateVal;
            }
            else if (deleteVal != null && insertVal == null && updateVal == null)
            {
                return deleteVal;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credit to [@Crowcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276469/crowcoder) for pointing me in the right direction.